# JavaScript Regex Ignore Case

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match a part of the string and it should be NOT case sensitive. I have the following code but I never get the replaced string.

```
var name = 'Mohammad Azam'
var result = name.replace('/' + searchText + '/gi', "<b>" + searchText + "</b>");
```

The searchText variable will be "moha" or "mo" or "moh".

How can I get the matching thing in bold tags.

Comment: What do you want to replace searchText with? Literal string 'searchText' or something else?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

/pattern/ has meaning when it's put in as a literal, not if you construct string like that. (I am not 100% sure on that.)

Try

```
var name = 'Mohammad Azam';
var searchText = 'moha';
var result = name.replace(new RegExp('(' + searchText + ')', 'gi'), "<b>$1</b>");
//result is <b>Moha</b>mmad Azam
```

EDIT:

Added the demo page for the above code.

[Demo →](http://jsbin.com/ixeji)

[Code](http://jsbin.com/ixeji/edit)

Comment: You **do not** have to construct RegExp's with a parenthesis

Comment: He wants to capture the match and surround it with <b> and </b> tags.
You can't do capturing without parenthesis.

Comment: Yes you can when the search string is identical to the replacement sans surrounding tags.

Comment: So, actually I should be sending the Regex object into the replace and not a string when performing these case operations. Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for new RegExp, which creates a dynamic regular expression - what you're trying to do now is match a string ( not a regexp object ) :

```
var name = 'Mohammad Azam', searchText='moha';

var result = name.replace(new RegExp(searchText, 'gi'), "" + searchText + ""); result
```

EDIT: Actually, this is probably what you were looking for, nevermind ^

```
var name = 'Mohammad Azam', searchText='moha';
name.match( new RegExp( searchText , 'gi' ) )[0]
name // "Moha"
```

Comment: heh, I confused myself with what you were looking for - let me know if either of those workout.