# Regex does not ignore case of letters

Tags: jquery, regex

I have this Regex below that I use together with [Textcomplete](http://yuku-t.com/jquery-textcomplete/), check if someone writes `#` or `@` together with a parameter

**Regex:**

```
/\B#(\w+)$/
```

I load some names from my database, and you can search them with either `#` or `@`. Lets say that in the database it contains Stackoverflow.

If I write #Stackoverflow it works since I wrote a big S letter.
but if I write #stackoverflow it dont work because of the small s letter.

My question is how can I change the regex so it ignore small or big letters?

**Updated with script**

```
$('textarea').textcomplete([
               { // html
                   mentions: Companies,
                   match: /\B#(\w+)\i$/,
                   search: function (term, callback) {
                       callback($.map(this.mentions, function (mention) {
                           return mention.indexOf(term) === 0 ? mention : null;
                       }));
                   },
                   template: function (value) {
                       return '<img src="/emoji/' + value + '.png"></img>' + value;
                   },
                   index: 1,
                   replace: function (mention) {
                       return '#' + mention + ' ';
                   }
               }
            ],
            { appendTo: 'body' }).overlay([
                   {
                       match: /\B#\w+/g,
                       css: {
                           'background-color': '#d8dfea',
                       }
                   }
            ])
```

To show you that It dont work, I created it at [codePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmZmbv).

Comment: The `/\B#(\w+)$/` regex matches all lower- and uppercase Latin letters `[a-zA-Z]`. Without a working fiddle it is difficult to judge what is necessary. I guess you need to turn all your matches into lower case for it to work.

Comment: Try `return mention.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) === 0 ? mention : null;`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the codepen does not work for me :(. Did you try my above suggestion.

Comment: That dont work either, sorry for the late responce

Comment: You codepen started working for me :) and [here is an updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdQzqZ). It works in fact. I only modified the callback at the end as `return mention.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) === 0 ? mention : null;`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx Ignore Case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395542/regex-ignore-case)

Comment: Yep you are correct it works, I'm sorry i made a misstype i didnt notice. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the callback at the end as

```
return mention.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) === 0 ? mention : null;
```

[Here is an updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdQzqZ).

Now, it works:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `/i` option to ignore the case. So your regex will be

```
/\B#(\w+)$/i
```

**EDIT:**

Just checked your regex and it works fine without the `/i`

**[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bX6hY9/1)**

Comment: why would it be a joke?

Comment: @stribizhev:- Yes you are correct. That is not required. Updated my answer. Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: I have removed my previous comments. Now, this answer offers a solution that is identical to what OP is already using.

Comment: I updated it again with a codepen link so you can see what i mean