# RegEx to capture all variations of the same search time

Tags: regex

I want to capture a few search terms customers might search for using RegEx, so I can direct them all to the same page.

For example, if the search term was house plant, i'd want to capture:
'House Plant', 'house plant', 'houseplant', 'Houseplant', 'house-plant', 'House-Plant' ect

I've been using a RegEx tester to try and figure it out, but why does this expression, not capture 'houseplant' or 'house plant':
`/house(\s|\S)plant/g`

It only matches 'house plant' and not 'houseplant'

Also I can't find anything for the upper or lower case options - is RegEx not case sensitive?

Comment: You need to use `?` after `(\s|\S)`. Or just use `[\s\S]?`. or `.?` with a dotall option on. Or, `\W?` if the char should be a non-word char (to exclude `houserplant`-like matches)

Comment: For the case-sensitivity option, which language is the regex being used in?

Comment: Javascript/React

Comment: @user2953989 [RegEx Ignore Case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24395542/1115360).

Comment: Thank you both! I use \W? and the ignore case and that works perfectly :)