# I want to look for matches only after special character in regex

Tags: json, regex

I am using regex in json. I am trying to get email that doesnt have “abc” on it.

`^((?!abc).)*$` but only after @ on the email.

If email is abc@gmail.com it shouldnt match and if email is james@abc.com it should match.

How do i write a regex to say match if email doesnt contain “abc” after @

Comment: What if the email is james@abcgamil.com or james@xyzabcqwe.com. Should it match or not?

Comment: Yes point is look for matches only after @ and discard anything before @

Answer (score 1):

You were very nearly there.

```
^.*@((?!abc).)*$
```

should do the trick

Comment: Hey thankyou so much, it worked. I was wondering if I can ignore case of abc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395542/regex-ignore-case/24395578

Comment: Im not sure why it’s not working with my json

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the flavor of regexp being used by the downstream application. Each language tends to have a slightly different variation, but you can try some of these "tricks".

- Use the `+` after an expression to indicate it must appear at least once.
- For example, `[^\@]+` means a non-at-sign character must appear at least once preceding the at-sign.
- You can replace `[^\@]+` with `(?:\w|\.|\_|\-)+` to prevent entry of invalid names preceding "@" (for example, you cannot have a percent-sign in an email username)
- Use `(?![Aa][Bb][Cc])` instead of `(?!abc)` so that the "abc" portion is not case sensitive.
- If "abc" doesn't need to be right after the "@" then add a non-capturing group representing characters which may appear before "abc" (see the fourth example below)

```py
# lowercase "abc" which must be right after the "@"
"^[^\@]+\@(?!abc)(?:\w|\_|\-|\.)+(?:[.]\w{2,4})+$"

# case insensitive "abc" which must be right after the "@" (which may be preceded by any non-"@" characters)
"^[^\@]+\@(?![Aa][Bb][Cc])(?:\w|\_|\-|\.)+(?:[.]\w{2,4})+$"

# case insensitive "abc" which must be right after the "@" (which may be preceded by valid characters, such as alphabet letters, period, underscore)
"^(?:\w|\.|\_|\-)+\@(?![Aa][Bb][Cc])(?:\w|\_|\-|\.)*(?:[.]\w{2,4})+$"

# case insensitive "abc" which may be preceded by other valid characters
"^(?:\w|\.|\_|\-)+\@(?!(?:\w|\_|\-|\.)*[Aa][Bb][Cc])(?:\w|\_|\-|\.)*(?:[.]\w{2,4})+$"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
^[^@]*@(?!.*abc).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kp5iDz/1).

If there can't be `abc` *immediately* after `@`, you need to remove `.*` before `abc` in the pattern and use

```js
^[^@]*@(?!abc).*
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kp5iDz/2).

The regex matches any zero or more chars other than `@`, a `@`, then makes sure there is no `abc` after any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible immediately to the right of `@`, and then matches the rest of the string.

Note you need to use an inline modifier `(?i)` to match the `abc` in a case insensitive way, or use a `[aA][bB][cC]` workaround if the inline flags are not supported:

```js
(?i)^[^@]*@(?!.*abc).*
^[^@]*@(?!.*[aA][bB][cC]).*
```